# Angular2 directive not applied when loading content from JSON in ionic2

Tags: json, angular, ionic2, angular-directive

I'm using a custom directive to display a tooltip in my pages.
Here is the directive I use :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '.showTooltip' })

export class TooltipDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    handleClick(event: Event) {
        if (this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.showTooltip(this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute("rel"));
        }
    }

    showTooltip(text) {
        console.log(this.renderer);
        let spanElement = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "span");
        this.renderer.createText(spanElement, text);
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(spanElement, "class", "tooltip");
        this.renderer.listen(spanElement, 'click', (event) => {
        console.log(spanElement);
            spanElement.remove();
        });
    }
}
```

When I use this code in a page, the tooltip is correctly displayed.

```
<span class="showTooltip" rel="Tooltip displayed!">click here</span>
```

But most of my content is loaded from a JSON file (where the span above is stored). When the content is loaded, then the directive is not applied.
Just like if the event hasn't be binded or something like that.

Here is the constructor of the page that loads the content :

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private platform: Platform, private http: Http) {

```
var url = 'assets/data/file.json';

if (this.platform && this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
    url = "/android_asset/www/" + url;
}

this.http.get(url)
    .map(result => result.json())
    .subscribe(item => this.items = item);
;
```

I precise I'm quite begineer with angular2/ionic2.

Thanks

Comment: Have you declared your directive in your module? (In declarations array)

Comment: Yes it's declared in the app.modules.ts